# Solution with generating function - unclarity

Tags: probability

Consider a gambling game in which you stake a given amount A and you
roll a fair die. If $k$ spots turn up, you multiply your stake by
$2(k-1)/5$. You can stop at any time and reclaim the
current stake. What are the mean and variance of your stake after $n$ rolls?
(Ignore any effects of rounding to integer amounts of currency.)

Hello!
We have defined generating function:
$G_n(z)$ for the current stake after $n$ rolls
$$G_0(z) = z^A$$
$$G_n(z) = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{6}G_{n-1}(z^{2(k-1)/5})$$
I understand, that Expected value: 
$$E=G_n'(1) = G_{n-1}'(1) = \dots = G_0'(1) = A$$
But I don't understand why $VarX = ((\frac{22}{15})^n - 1)A^2 $
Look at my point of view, please:
$$Var = G_n''(1) + G_n' (1) -  (G_n'(1))^2 = G_n''(1) + A - A^2 $$
$$G_n''(1) = G_{n-1}''(1) = \dots = G_0''(1) = A(A-1) $$

Help me, please

Comment: Derivation and evaluation do not commute.

Comment: Ok, So look now $$G'_n(z) = Az^{A-1} $$ $$ G''_n(z) = A(A-1)z^{A-2} $$ When we avaluate $z=1$ we will get the same problem.